# Trouble when Introducing VTK 9.2.2 to winui3 C++

Tags: vtk, c++-winrt, winui-3

I am currently working with QT/QML. The product I am programming is only for windows based. so, I am going to use winui3 (not considering WPF, WinForms, and MFC. they are not easy to use C++ or very old).
As you probably know, winui3 can be developed with WINRT/C++, it looks like almost UWP. I have tried to display VTK render window with having the red background color on the MainWindow.xaml. but when the software is launching and closing, I can see the red background in a very short time and be expected the red background is hidden on the main window.
could you let me know how to avoid this. if someone has had experiences about WPF and VTK C++, I expect the similar solution may be applied.

I posted this in the VTK discourse as well but post hear to get quick solution.

Comment: Please show a [mcve], take the [tour] and read [ask]. As for the question, you'll quickly discover that WinUI in combination with C++/WinRT is **extremely** hard to use. And when things do go wrong, you're mostly on your own. Very few people using it, and very few resources available online.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am not in the office. I will update with full source code soon. thank you for your kind words. :)